# Dispose of Control but keep its value (for USER/GDI efficency)

Tags: vb.net, gdi

I am making a program that will require the user to enter some information into an array of controls once and then leave the window open for a lengthy period of time.

I have made my own set of custom controls that are not the most USER/GDI efficient, one of which being an expander control to show/hide a group of controls. When the group is closed the panel of controls is purely hidden as opposed to disposed of (this is to retain their values). Is it possible to make the program store these values in memory and then recall these values when the expander is opened (and controls inside are generated again)?

Comment: the way to `make the program store the values in memory` is to write something like a class to save the values.  I doubt it would be more efficient to recreate a bunch of controls **and** have a set of classes for data persistence, but it is hard to tell with so little info.  Maybe working to make the expander more efficient would be...more efficient?

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, I agree that the best thing would be to try and make the controls more efficient. I'll pursue this